# Presented View Controller from custom modal presentation not autorotating in iOS7 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate not being called properly

Tags: ios7, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate, presentviewcontroller, custom-transition

I have a view controller that I am presenting with a Custom Modal Presentation

```
myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
myViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Works as expected but for some reason (in iOS7) the presented view controller is not autorotating when the device orientation changes. Apparently the (presented view controller's) method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
}
```

is not being called in iOS7 when the device orientation changes. It's only called once when it is first shown. When I run it on iOS8 it works fine and shouldAutorotate is being called properly. Its strange because it can only be presented in Portrait.  If I try to present the view in landscape it does not work.  I have checked all my parent view controllers and they are all setup correctly and I have all orientations set in my plist and my app delegate methods.  Any body have any ideas as to why this works in iOS8 but not iOS7?